# Не делается INSERT в базу данных использую Sqlite.swift

Tags: база-данных, ios, swift, sqlite, swift3

Я пытаюсь использовать [Sqlite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) для управления базой данных в своём iOS app. Но `insert` почему-то не работает, тупо заходит в `catch` и ничего не записывает в базу. Хотя `table` успешно создается

вот приблизительный код который я использую (как и написано в туториале)
`

```
import SQLite

let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
db = try Connection("\(path)/my_db.sqlite3")

let users = Table("users")
let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
let name = Expression<String?>("name")
let email = Expression<String>("email")

try db.run(users.create { t in
    t.column(id, primaryKey: true)
    t.column(name)
    t.column(email, unique: true)
})
// CREATE TABLE "users" (
//     "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
//     "name" TEXT,
//     "email" TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
// )

do {
   let insert = users.insert(name <- "Alice", email <- "alice@mac.com")
   let rowid = try db.run(insert)
} catch{
   print("Not inserted")
}
```

Может я чё-то упустил или что-то другое надо использовать для баз данных в  iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Внимательно всмотритесь в эту строчку:

```
t.column(email, unique: true)
```

Здесь указано что e-mail должен быть уникальный. Таким образом, если попадает в блок catch, то произошла попытка добавить еще одного пользователся с таким же email.

Для наглядности проверки пропишите, к примеру:

```
do{
   let insert = users.insert(name <- "Alice", email <- "alice\(arc4random_uniform(9999))@mac.com")
   let rowid = try db.run(insert)
} catch{
   print("Not inserted")
}
```

Ну и выводите результат:

```
for user in try db.prepare(users) {
    print("id: \(user[id]), name: \(user[name]), email: \(user[email])")
}
```

Comment: Да в том и дело, не могу добавить в пустую базу, где нет вообще никаких записей. Но не получается.

Comment: @Alexander какая ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

я может ошибаюсь, но вместо
let users = Table("users")

попробуешь использовать

var users = Table("users")

Comment: Если вы не уверены,  попробуйте создать минимальный пример кода.